# Authentication required by wireless network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, certificate, authentication

I would like to use a wireless network from Ubuntu. In the network drop-down menu I select a network (this is a University network I have an account there). Then I get a windows with the following fields:

> Wireless Security: [WPA&WPA2
>   Enterprise]
>  Authentication:
>   [Tunneled TLS]
>  Anonymous Identity:
>   []
>  CA Certificate: [(None)]
>   Inner Authentication: [some
>   letters]
>  User Name: []
>   Password: []

I put there my user name and password and do not change default value and leave "Anonymous Identity"blank.

As a result of that I get "Authentication required by wireless network". How can I solve this problem?

**I think it is important to notice that our system administrator tried to find some files (which are probably needed to be used as "CA Certificate").** He said that he does not know where this file is located on Ubuntu (he support only Windows). So, probably this is direction I need to go. I need to find this file. But may be I am wrong. May be something else needs to be done.

Could you pleas help me with that?

Comment: You say "Inner Authentication: [some letters]". Did you select the correct protocols for Auth and Inner Auth or did you guess them?

Comment: Would this happen to be an *eduroam* network perchance?

Answer (score 1):

ssl certificates are located in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

also Tunneled TLS (TTLS) may be the wrong authentication type, try MSCHAP V2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=249654